# Return pair of iterators from function

Tags: c++, stl

Sometimes I need to return a range as a result of function. Is there a standard way to do so using only C++ and STL?

I can use:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator> findRange();
```

but this is really quite long sentence.

I can use [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) , but want to stay with pure iterators, not recalculating to size.
I was sure that [std::ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) or [std:view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) should help, but can’t find the proper way to use them for this purpose.

Of course, I can define my own structure for this, but is there a build-in straightforward solution?

Comment: In case it helps you sleep better at night, [`std::multimap::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) returns a pair of iterators exactly the way you show.

Comment: With `std::span<const int>`, you could access an equivalent pair of iterators, with just different   syntax: `.begin()` and `.end()` instead of `.first` and `.second`.

Comment: Use a `using` statement to simplify the declaration of `findRange()`, eg: `using c_iter = std::vector<int>::const_iterator; using c_iter_pair = std::pair<c_iter, c_iter>; c_iter_pair findRange();`

Comment: You're right, my bad

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I am not sure that this is the best way in the modern (C++ 17, 20) versions of C++. This implementation is for C++ 14 and I hoped that people invented something better.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this is almost the same as "I can define my own structure for this" but with alias. For sure, this works. My question was if there is already something in place for this in modern C++. You know, when I ask people curious why I just don't use "using", when I don't ask people cry "why don't you use existing one and invite the bicycle"? So, I just don't want to create my own implementation for possible existing thing and that's why asking and immediately (somebody automated this?) got minus vote for the question. :)

Comment: @Eugene, as I stated in my original question, I don't want additional excessive operations (performance concern) when the second iterator will be recalculated to size and then when I request for end() will be recalculated back to iterator.

Comment: @DamirTenishev there is nothing existing for this, `std::pair` is your best choice given your requirement. The `using` is just to reduce the verbosity of the code.